# How can I calculate the heat caused by a proton beam shot at a target?

Tags: particle-physics

I assume the formula has to include:

Beam energy, beam duration, nº of particles in the beam, target density (eg iridium), and target mass.

From CERN [experiments](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/25202246.pdf) I know that *only a small %* of the energy beam ends as heat.

I also assume that all types of collisions are going on: inelastic, elastic, perfectly elastic, and perfectly inelastic.

I would appreciate the easiest possible formula to understand. I have 0 background in physics.

Comment: if the beam stops in the target this is very easy, it's just the total energy of the protons. If it goes through the target and comes out the other side with less energy this is very difficult, and there are programs devotred to calculating it like SRIM.

Comment: @RogerJBarlow thanks, but if the all the beam stops in the target, some of that energy (the mass in E=mc2) would still be inside the target after having lost all of its kinetic energy, and therefore not all the energy E could be attributed to the heat. I mean, part of the resulting E would correspond to the mass, and part to the heat. Right?

Comment: also with this calculator: https://calc.weingos.com/ I get that in the cern experiment more than 99% of the beam is stopped by the target, but in the cern paper heat accounts for only around 2% of the initial beam energy

Comment: @RogerJBarlow In part I agree. This is a complex process and something like SRIM is really the only answer to this question. James' contention that long-lived massive particles remain in the material is probably negligible. However, for any reasonable sized target, muons and neutrinos will not be stopped, and will carry away energy. Most targets (at cern) stop the proton beam, but the whole point of the target is to produce particles on the other side. So they are also thin enough to allow kaons, pions, X-rays, etc. to pass through. IDK a quick way to estimate this so I'm not posting answer.

Comment: @James that calculator is for Xrays not protons.  "Just the total energy" meant "Just the total kinetic energy", sorry if that wasn't clear. Targets vary, there are thick targets and thin targets and beam energies vary from low (below pion production threshold) to high, so it's dangerous to generalise. But any energy that goes into the target and doesn't come out becomes heat, eventually, so the 2% figure doesn't make sense